# How do I load NPM modules in the browser?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

I want to use redux-thunk client-side (in browser) but the only implementation I find is an NPM module. How can I load an NPM module in a browser? What is the correct way? Webpack to bundle?

I ended up using Webpack.

Comment: Webpack or Browserify can bundle CommonJS modules, assuming they do not dedepend on the Node-specific internal modules (in which case it was probably not designed for browsers).

Comment: http://jspm.io/, perhaps. Can handle npm, git repos...

Comment: But is webpack or jspm.io the only way to go? It isn't possible to load it directly in Javascript client-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack or Browserify will both work fine.

- WebPack is newer and makes slightly smaller modules
- Browserify has been around longer and has more users.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use this library in for demo purposes, or some examples, you can get it from wzrd.in: https://wzrd.in/standalone/redux-thunk@latest

This website is browserify-as-a-service, that can build and return you any module from npm.

But be aware, this thing should not be used in production, because it is not intended as a highload solution. For that case you need to prepare a build with some tools, like Webpack or Browserify on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Using webpack will be the best option, especially if you are building a react app and are using webpack for react